# How to combine api call for each element with call of list with rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I have 2 api methods.

```
@POST("/api/photos/")
Single<List<Photo>> getPhotos();

@POST("/api/user/profile")
Single<Profile> getProfile(@Query("photoId") String photoId);
```

I want to return Single < List < Pair < Photo,Profile>>> after combining some rx operations and this api methods. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution

```
public class TestCombining {
    public Single<List<Pair<Photo, Profile>>> test(ApiInterface apiInterface) {
        return apiInterface.getPhotos()
                .flattenAsObservable(photos -> photos)
                .flatMap(photo -> apiInterface.getProfile(photo.getId())
                        .map(profile -> new Pair<>(photo, profile)).toObservable())
                .toList();
    }

    interface ApiInterface {
        Single<List<Photo>> getPhotos();

        Single<Profile> getProfile(String photoId);
    }

    interface Profile {
        String getPhotoId();
    }

    interface Photo {
        String getId();
    }
}
```